# BMW 520d e60 2008 diesel engine won't start after switching off

Tags: engine, starting, bmw, diesel

I have a strange behaviour of my car. Engine starts well at any weather condition but after driving and switched off engine cannot start again for 20 - 40 minutes. After this time it starts like nothing happened. This is happening a few times in the 3 month. The battery is full, the lights on panel is on but no any sound of starter motor.

Please your advise would be very appreciate.

UPDATE: Today after some time of driving engine won't start again. Later on I have scanned for OBD faulty codes and appeared P14A3 - Powertrain . After my research  found very close and similar issue [here](http://bmwenthusiasts.co.uk/forum/viewtopic.php?f=109&t=13228). Might helps to someone else.

Comment: When this happens, you get absolutely no sound (no click or anything) from the starter when you turn the key?

Comment: Only can hear I think the fuel pump start and no other sounds. I think this problem is related to electronic and hot engine .

Comment: Sounds like a thermostat or temperature sender problem, but my knowledge of diesels only qualifies me to speculate from a great distance. Good luck!